# Dot product in complex plane and perpendicularity

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been watching [this](https://youtu.be/M0Sa8fLOajA?list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D&t=735) video(don't have to click the link) and have a quick question. The professor says that if the numbers are complex, we must *conjugate* one vector while checking perpendicularity.
$a^Tb=0$ changes to ${\bar{a}}^Tb=0$.
In $\mathbb{C^1}$ the two complex numbers $a=e^{i\theta}$ and $b=e^{i(\theta+\pi/2)}$ are clearly perpendicular. However the dot product ${\bar{a}}^Tb=e^{-i\theta}e^{i(\theta+\pi/2)}=e^{i\pi/2} = i\ne 0$. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: If you are after orthogonality in the geometric sense, you need to take the real part of the complex dot product. Orthogonality in the sense of the complex dot product is stronger than orthogonality in the real sense.

Comment: Ah ok if I get this correctly, orthogonal vectors don't represent the perpendicular vectors in geometric sense. They're a subset. That is,  two complex numbers can have a phase difference of $\pi/2$ and yet we don't call them orthogonal?first time studying these.. thank you so much:).

Comment: Yes, orthogonality should be invariant under multiplication with nonzero scalars (for example to ensure that nonvanishing orthogonal vectors are linearly independent). When you aren't interested in this behaviour, you look at the underlying $\mathbb{R}$-vector space instead of the complex vector space structure.

Comment: that `nonzero scalar` we multiply to the `orthogonal vector` can be a complex number. I somewhat see why the definition ditches geometry.. Thanks again you're awesomeXD